# Simple Validator in PHP not working

Tags: php, validation

I created a little form validator with PHP and having some problems with it.
MY VIEW FILE is here :

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php if( isset($status) ) : ?>
    <p class="notice"><?php echo $status; ?> </p>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Your Name : </label>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="email">Your Email : </label>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
            </li>
        </ul>



    </form>
```

and here's my little controller :

```
<?php
require 'index.tmpl.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $name  = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);

    if (empty($name) || empty($email)) {
        $status = "Please provide a name and a valid email address";
    }

    echo $name;

}

?>
```

Now what happens is that , when I open up the page and leave the form fields blank and submit it ,it just reloads ,does not echo anything.

Comment: Are you using a framework, perhaps variables don't get passed to the view one-on-one?

Comment: add the framework name .....

Comment: Print your `$status` variable.

Comment: No framework is being used

Answer (score 1):

The `<form action=""`  points to the location where the form will be submitted. If blank, it submits the form back to itself.

```
<form action="yourLittleController.php" method="POST">
```

Edited with more info:

in php, post is not POST. Example here:  https://eval.in/89002

make sure you have

```
method="POST">
```

and not

```
method="POST">
```

Comment: Yes ,but i'm requiring it in the controller file

Answer (score 1):

You want to echo $status, not $name.

Comment: Nothing will be echoed anyway since "POST" != "post"

Answer (score 1):

How about moving the `require` line to below the `if`?

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $name  = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);

    if (empty($name) || empty($email)) {
        $status = "Please provide a name and a valid email address";
    }

    echo $name;
}

require 'index.tmpl.php';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should mention your second file name in your view file's form's action attribute like   action = "controller.php"